# Why use a Fluent Interface?

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

When comparing to classic properties, what's the big gain of using it ?

I know the repeating of the instance name is gone, but that's all ?

```
public class PropClass
{
  public Object1 object1 { get; set; }
  public Object2 object2 { get; set; }
}

PropClass propClass = new PropClass();
propClass.object1 = o1;
propClass.object2 = o2;

public class FluentClass
{
    public Object1 object1 { get; private set; }
    public Object2 object2 { get; private set; }

    public FluentClass SetObject1(Object1 o1)
    {
        object1 = o1;
        return this;
    }

    public FluentClass SetObject2(Object1 o2)
    {
        object1 = o2;
        return this;
    }
}

FluentClass fluentClass = new FluentClass().SetObject1(o1).SetObject1(o2);
```

Comment: `Fluent Interfaces` are useful when dealing with `Specification Pattern`. It chains n number of specifications as one as given in [How to combine conditions dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406492/how-to-combine-conditions-dynamically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO there's no big gain of setting properties with fluent interface, especially with C# 3.0 class initializers. Fluent interfaces become more interesting when you start chaining methods and operations.

Comment: Not for setting properties maybe, but for chaining operations, for example, multiply by 5, add 3, divide by 7, etc...

Comment: `Fluent Interfaces` are useful when dealing with `Specification Pattern`. It chains n number of specifications as one as given in [How to combine conditions dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406492/how-to-combine-conditions-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how it's used.  In your example, there's not much point in using a fluent interface.

On the other hand, fluent interface works really well for things like builders, especially when you chain multiple fluent builders together (e.g. car builder / engine builder).  I've used [Test Data Builders](http://nat.truemesh.com/archives/000714.html) quite extensively and they work really well.  You can do the same thing without a fluent interface, but it's not so nice to use.

Furthermore, there is the Domain Specific Language angle that Martin Fowler [explains here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).

The only problem is that people sometimes go a bit crazy with fluent interfaces and create overly verbose APIs, but that's less of a fluent interface problem and more of an application/implementation problem, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Fluent pattern (Builder) will be best benefit when you want to reduce code duplication and reduce dependency between each class. For C# 3.5+, you can create your fluent pattern by creating method extension like LINQ or the following code.

```
public BaseControl
{
    public void RenderControl(HTMLWriter writer) {}
}

public TextBox : BaseControl
{
    public string Text { get;set; }
}

public static T TabIndex<T>(this T control, int index) where T : BaseControl {}
```

After you have the above code, you can use TabIndex to set tab index control that you want like this.

```
BaseControl control1 = new BaseControl();
control1.TabIndex(1);

// Moreover, you can use this for any devired controls like this
TextBox control2 = new TextBox()
{
    Text = "test"
};

// The following method still return TextBox control.
control2.TabIndex(2);
```

As you see, you can reduce unnecessary code for BaseControl class. But you can plug it alter like I show. This concept works on a lot of classes that have high rate of coupling.

By the way, I like this pattern because it make my code easy to read like the following code.

```
var pmLogOnName = Html.CreatePopUpMenu("pmLogOnName")
                      .AddMenuItem("mLogOnName-RememberMe", "Remember UserName", isCheckBox: true, isSelected: true);

Html.CreateTextBox("txtLogOnName", 1)
    .BindData(Model, x => x.LogOnName, "showError")
    .WaterMark(LogOnView.LogOnName)
    .BindMenu(pmLogOnName)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a VB.Net `With` block.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't necessarily a big advantage, in my opinion, or simple classes like you have above (classes with a few properties).  It's a different semantic that some developers are comfortable with on one hand.  On the other hand, I think it's very advantageous in certain arenas like ASP.NET MVC...  I use the Telerik MVC controls which uses a fluent interface and it is very nice to setup the controls with; the MS way requires using collections and anonymous classes, and it's not so convenient to use.

HTH.