# How to combine conditions dynamically?

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, fluent-interface, specification-pattern

This question is an enhancement to the already answered question [How to apply multiple filter conditions (simultaneously) on a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384357/how-to-apply-multiple-filter-conditions-simultaneously-on-a-list)

In the above mentioned question we have a method that applied `AND` operator on all the specifications. This is achieved by using LINQ `All` operator on the specifications.

```
    public static List<Product> GetProductsUisngAndFilters(List<Product> productList, List<Specification<Product>> productSpecifications)
    {
        return productList.Where(p => productSpecifications.All(ps => ps.IsSatisfiedBy(p))).ToList();
    }
```

We need to create a new method (GetProductsUisngDynamicFilters) that is capable of performing `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` specifications (and a mix of that). Any idea how we can solve this?

**Filter Methods**

```
public static class ProductFilterHelper
{
     public static List<Product> GetProductsUisngAndFilters(List<Product> productList, List<Specification<Product>> productSpecifications)
    {
        return productList.Where(p => productSpecifications.All(ps => ps.IsSatisfiedBy(p))).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();

        Product p1 = new Product(false, 99);
        Product p2 = new Product(true, 99);
        Product p3 = new Product(true, 101);
        Product p4 = new Product(true, 110);
        Product p5 = new Product(false, 110);

        list.Add(p1);
        list.Add(p2);
        list.Add(p3);
        list.Add(p4);
        list.Add(p5);

        double priceLimit = 100;

        List<Specification<Product>> specifications = new List<Specification<Product>>();
        specifications.Add(new OnSaleSpecificationForProduct());
        specifications.Add(new PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct(priceLimit));
        specifications.Add(new PriceGreaterThan105());

        List<Product> selectedList = ProductFilterHelper.GetProductsBasedOnInputFilters(list, specifications);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

**Abstract Specifications**

```
public abstract class Specification<T>
{
    public abstract bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj);

    public AndSpecification<T> And(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        return new AndSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }

    public OrSpecification<T> Or(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        return new OrSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }

    public NotSpecification<T> Not(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        return new NotSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }
}

public abstract class CompositeSpecification<T> : Specification<T>
{
    protected readonly Specification<T> _leftSide;
    protected readonly Specification<T> _rightSide;

    public CompositeSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
    {
        _leftSide = leftSide;
        _rightSide = rightSide;
    }
}
```

**Generic Specifications**

```
public class AndSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public AndSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
        : base(leftSide, rightSide)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj)
    {
        return _leftSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj) && _rightSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj);
    }
}

public class OrSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public OrSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
        : base(leftSide, rightSide)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj)
    {
        return _leftSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj) || _rightSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj);
    }
}

public class NotSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public NotSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
        : base(leftSide, rightSide)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj)
    {
        return _leftSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj) && !_rightSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj);
    }
}
```

**Product Specifications**

```
public class OnSaleSpecificationForProduct : Specification<Product>
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(Product product)
    {
        return product.IsOnSale;
    }
}

public class PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct : Specification<Product>
{
    private readonly double _price;
    public PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct(double price)
    {
        _price = price;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(Product product)
    {
        return product.Price > _price;
    }
}

public class PriceGreaterThan105 : Specification<Product>
{

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(Product product)
    {
        return product.Price > 105;
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class Product
{
    private bool _isOnSale;
    private double _price = 0.0;

    public Product(bool isOnSale)
        : this(isOnSale, 0.0)
    {
        _isOnSale = isOnSale;
    }

    public Product(double price)
        : this(false, price)
    {
        _price = price;
    }

    public Product(bool isOnSale, double price)
    {
        _price = price;
        _isOnSale = isOnSale;
    }

    public bool IsOnSale
    {
        get { return _isOnSale; }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the code you provided, it seems to me that your logic for combining filters is sound. The problem is the `List<Specification<T>>`. By having compound specification in place, you can combine them and only pass a `Specification<T>` (which would be a `CompositeSpecification<T>`):

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();

        Product p1 = new Product(false, 99);
        Product p2 = new Product(true, 99);
        Product p3 = new Product(true, 101);
        Product p4 = new Product(true, 110);
        Product p5 = new Product(false, 110);

        list.Add(p1);
        list.Add(p2);
        list.Add(p3);
        list.Add(p4);
        list.Add(p5);

        double priceLimit = 100;

         var specification =
             new OnSaleSpecificationForProduct()
                 .And(new PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct(priceLimit)
                              .Or(new PriceGreaterThan105()));

        List<Product> selectedList = ProductFilterHelper.GetProductsBasedOnInputFilters(list, specification);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

And your filtering method becomes:

```
 public static List<Product> GetProductsUisngDynamicFilters(List<Product> productList, Specification<Product> productSpecification)
    {
        return productList.Where(p => productSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(p))
                          .ToList();
    }
```

As a side note, you should consider moving the `Or`, `And` and `Not` method from the abstract `Specification<T>` to an extension method. And perhaps use interfaces instead.